# Dial rotation jump

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im working on a dial that rotates when a user touches it and drags it around. So far so good, but when the dial gets to more than 360, the value goes back to 0, making the animation jump backwards around the dial instead of continuing.

```
dialRotation = (atan2(event->localY()-circleCenterY, event->localX()-circleCenterX) * (180/M_PI));
```

Does anyone know how to stop it from jumping?

Comment: Show us the code that actually performs the animation.

Comment: senderImage->rotationZ(dialRotation);

Comment: You don't seem to be using Objective-C.  Why is this question even tagged objective-c?

Comment: Im using C++ and since its touch related I thought in the iPhone forums would be a good place to ask.

Comment: You haven't shown anything that has anything to do with iOS or Objective-C programming, so it's very hard to help you.  Edit your question and paste in all of the code that handles a touch event and applies an animation.

Comment: Why does it need to be obj c? The same principles of a dial rotating would apply to any language.

Comment: Well, you tagged it with “iphone” and “Objective-C”, so I would expect the question to have something to do with those things.  And even though you talk about “making the animation jump backwards”, you still haven't posted the Objective-C code that actually applies an animation to a view or a layer.  If you're using some C++ wrapper instead of Objective-C, you need to tell us about that wrapper.

Comment: I tagged it with those tags because iPhone dev is very popular and what it actually is for (BB10 dev) is not very popular. I would be able to translate any objc code into c++. If I had tagged BB10 no one would have responded, instead I got a decent few responses from user1118321 which have helped immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the existing value to determine if you should go beyond 360 or not. Perhaps something like this:

```
currentValue = dialRotation;
dialRotation = (atan2(event->localY()-circleCenterY, event->localX()-circleCenterX) * (180/M_PI));
dialRotation = 360.0 * floor(fmod(currentValue, 360.0)) + dialRotation;
```

I think this will work in the negative direction, too, though I sometimes get confused by `fmod()`s behavior for negative numbers, so be sure to check it.

Comment: Could you explain your answer more, what is currentValue and newAngle?

Comment: `currentValue` is the value of the control when you decide you need to change it because the user pressed it, or whatever. `newAngle` is the usually the result of something like `atan2(y,x);` where y,x are the coordinates of the mouse press or touch relative to the center of the dial. (This assumes you want 0 degrees to be horizontal and positive degrees to be in the counter-clockwise direction.)

Comment: This still jumps back to 0 when the user goes past 360, making the dial jump back rather than carry on following the finger.

Comment: What is the value of `currentValue` and `newAngle` when you see that happen?

Comment: I've updated the code to use the same naming convention you used in yours. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Im getting strange values as soon as I start using your formula Debug: -5.59934 
Debug: -2163.63 
Debug: -1541.98 
Debug: -36607.3

Comment: With your new code, still jumps, its gets to 180 around and then jumps to -180 (dialRotation)

Comment: Sorry, `atan2()` produces values in the range -pi to pi. I thought it was 0 to 2pi. You can just add 180 degrees to the result of the `atan2()` line if it's less than 0. I have another idea I'll post below in a separate answer that might be easier, though.

Comment: Adding 180 results in the same issue, the dial jumps backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to get the delta (the change) between the previous value and the current value and just add that to what you already have. As long as the difference is not greater than 180 degrees, that might work better. Something like this:

```
// In your class declaration:
float normalizedRotation; // Always between 0 and 360 degrees
float previousNormalizedRotation;
float dialRotation; // current value, can be any valid value from -inf to +inf

// In your method:
normalizedRotation = (atan2(event->localY()-circleCenterY, event->localX()-circleCenterX) * (180/M_PI));
if (normalizedRotation < 0.0) normalizedRotation += 360.0;
float delta = normalizedRotation - previousNormalizedRotation;
previousNormalizedRotation = normalizedRotation;
dialRotation += delta;
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for another answer, appreciate it. This rotates the dial but when it gets to 359... then to 0, the dial jumps back again.